React Native with Hermes: libhermes_executor.so not found - Tried Everything
I'm developing a React Native app (react-native version 0.76.3) with Hermes enabled. Despite following all the documentation and various solutions, I'm facing the following error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libhermes_executor.so" not found

This issue occurs during runtime, and the app crashes immediately. I've spent hours debugging and trying all suggested solutions but with no success.
My Environment:
React Native version: 0.76.3
Hermes version: 0.11.0
NDK version: 25.2.9519653
Android Gradle Plugin version: 8.1.1
Hermes enabled: true (set in gradle.properties)
Device architecture: arm64-v8a

Things I've Tried
Validated Hermes Setup:
Checked APK Contents: Ran:
unzip -l android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk | grep hermes

3680024  01-01-1981 01:01   lib/arm64-v8a/libhermes.so
 894384  01-01-1981 01:01   lib/arm64-v8a/libhermestooling.so
2419020  01-01-1981 01:01   lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes.so
 533244  01-01-1981 01:01   lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermestooling.so

However, libhermes_executor.so is missing.
Updated Dependencies:
Reinstalled hermes-engine:
npm uninstall hermes-engine
npm install hermes-engine@0.11.0 --save

Cleared node_modules and reinstalled all dependencies
rm -rf node_modules
npm install

Ensured NDK Configuration:
Updated ndkVersion in android/build.gradle:
ext {
    ndkVersion = "25.2.9519653"
}

Verified local.properties contains:
ndk.dir=/path/to/android/ndk

Packaging Options: Added the following to android/app/build.gradle to ensure .so files are included:
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libhermes.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libhermes_executor.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libhermestooling.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes_executor.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermestooling.so'
}

Current Status
Despite all the steps above, the error persists, and libhermes_executor.so is still missing in the APK. It appears the Hermes integration for React Native might be misconfigured or broken for my setup.
Questions

How can I ensure libhermes_executor.so is properly included in the APK?
Is there a reliable way to debug Hermes and ensure all required .so files are packaged?
Has anyone encountered this issue with React Native 0.76.x and Hermes 0.11.0? If yes, how did you resolve it?

